# How to determine if the users gaze is on a GUI element? (HoloLens Unity.EventSystem code equivalent)

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, hololens

```
bool clickingGuiElement = false;
if (UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
{
    if (UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != null)
    {
        if (UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject
.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer>() != null)
        {
            // user is clicking on a UI element (button)
            clickingGuiElement = true;
        }
        else
            clickingGuiElement = false;
    }
    else
        clickingGuiElement = false;
}
else
    clickingGuiElement = false;
```

The code above is utilizing Unity's EventSystem. This small control structure serves the purpose of handling objects being currently clicked on. It accomplishes the task of setting a boolean to inform the program whether the user is clicking on an UI element or not. In my case it is primarily utilized on buttons. Using this boolean output one can block UI clicks from propagating through the UI and interacting with any gameObjects that may be behind the UI.

Running through the code above on the HoloLens with breakpoints and/or printouts the result is always the same - false. The program never makes it into the first if statement on the HoloLens.

I need to be able to detect if the users airtap/clicker input, when they click, is on a UI element. If I know when a user clicks on an UI element, I can block it from propagating through the UI (as is done above, but, again, it works in the Editor and not on the HoloLens).

So, what substitutes the same EventSystem functionality achieved here (in the Editor) on the HoloLens?

P.S. I am using IPointerClickerHandler from UnityEngine.EventSystems in other parts of my code and it works fine, so I am not sure why this implementation utilizing the EventSystems isn't working. My best guess (from implementing features in the Editor vs the HoloLens) is that the 'Pointer' used in IsPointerOverGameObject isn't utilizing airtap input akin to mouse click input.

Comment: Have you tried IsPointerOverGameObject(1) ?

Comment: @Everts Yes, no go.

Comment: It might actually be 0. You should also make sure the HololensInputModule is correctly running.

Comment: @Everts Hololens Input and Hololens Input Module are both enabled and active in the scene. I am almost certain there is no problem with the Input as I can receive and use input on the Hololens. I have used Voice, Navigation gestures, Air Tap, et cetera. Problem is though the Air Tap is working, I need to detect if it is on a GUI element. And as you know, if it is, don't let the call propagate through the UI onto game objects behind it.

Comment: @Everts IsPointerOverGameObject(0) does not result in the desired behavior either, it should be noted.

Comment: This is a good read for starting with the Hololens: https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt788624

Comment: @Sorceri Figure 8, "InteractibleManager Class" is closely related to the code I use to ray cast onto my game objects. The hope was to modify the control structure provided in the op so that a boolean could be set if the users gaze is over a UI element (in my case, a button) when they select (air tap). And then use this boolean as a conditional when ray casting to prevent ray casting from occurring when a user air taps on a UI element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(GazeManager.Instance.IsGazingAtObject && GazeManager.Instance.HitObject != null)
{
    Debug.Log("guiElementName: " + GazeManager.Instance.HitObject.transform.name);
}
```

Did not find an EventSystem code equivalent in the end, however there is an easy solution in the 'GazeManager' script provided in the HoloToolkit provided by Microsoft.

Utilizing a simple check like this one above, one is able to determine if the users gaze is on a GUI element. Like so,

```
// Object assignment
GameObject cursor;

// If on GUI menu control structure
if (GazeManager.Instance.IsGazingAtObject && GazeManager.Instance.HitObject != null &&
    (GazeManager.Instance.HitObject.transform.name == "icon" || 
    GazeManager.Instance.HitObject.transform.name == "guiManager"))
{
    // Scale
    cursor.transform.localScale = halfScale;

    // Move the cursor to the point where the raycast hit
    //  to display it on the gui element
    cursor.transform.position = GazeManager.Instance.HitInfo.point;

    // Enable the cursor mesh
    cursor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
}
```

Self-explanatory really, the code above scales, moves, and displays a cursor gameObject on an GUI when the users gaze is on it.

*In my case [I used] the boolean output [from the EventSystem code attempting to] block UI clicks from propagating through the UI and interacting with any gameObjects that may be behind the UI.*

Rather then blocking the clicks, one can handle a users gaze input, when gazing at UI elements, properly using the GazeManager.

Answer (score 0):

Your UI Element needs to have a collider, and you need to use the raycast to detect if your ui element is being hit by the raycast. In the hololens the only way that I know of to detect that an element or game object has been hit is using gaze.

Edit: Upon clarification of the problem, you need to make sure that the layer that the raycast is able to hit is only the layer your button is on.

The question asks about detecting if a button is clicked, and the comments bring more understanding of the full problem, but the nature of the question is asked from the perspective of the person asking the questions's experience with other systems not from the understanding of how Hololens and Unity work together, to give the answer you are looking for is not possible because it's the wrong question. Everything in unity is essentially a game object, but they all can sit on different and multiple layers at the same time in the scene, you can see the layers in the top right in unity. The answer to resolve the problem is to specify the layer that the button is on, and that layer is not shared with other game objects which is not default behavior in Unity. When you are doing the raycast, you need to ignore all of the other layers, then you will no longer interact with the background objects behind the button. The link I included tells you how to do that. Once you have done that you would use the airtap event wired to the button like any other game object.

Here is a link on how to work with layers in Unity.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/416919/making-raycast-ignore-multiple-layers.html

Comment: I can't speak to this working or not, I instead implemented a different workaround utilizing hand detection

Comment: "*Upon clarification of the problem, you need to make sure that the layer that the raycast is able to hit is only the layer your button is on.*" The problem lies in detecting if the user clicked on a UI element. Raycasting needs to occur on the game objects themselves. Fundamental question here: How does the programmer detect if a user has clicked on a button when running on the Hololens? The reason for this question being that IsPointerOverGO doesn't return true for buttons when on the Hololens however, when the exact same if structure provided above is run in the Editor, it works perfectly.